# Command Line: get only part of line with grep

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with lines like this:

```
1   train   tree    11869   12227   .   +   .   leaf_id "ENSG00000223972"; root_id "ENST00000456328";
```

The line I'm searching for must have `train` in the second column and `tree` in the third column.

I only want to get the `leaf_id` starting with `ABC` inside the quotation marks. The rest of the line is not relevant. I tried already grep with regex and capture groups but that didn't work...

The columns are separated by `\t`, not spaces. Note that the last field is `leaf_id "ENSG00000223972"; root_id "ENST00000456328";`, there are spaces separating the entries there and not tabs.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. I assume this is an excerpt from a tab-separated file, and the format of each line is the same? Is it always `leaf_id` and then some string in double quotes (`" ... "`) followed by a `;`? Do you want to extract the string without or with the double quotes? Please edit your question to provide relevant information.

Comment: What else is in your file? I assume not all lines have `tree` and `train`, right? Please [edit] your question and add some examples that should _not_ be selected so we know what to avoid. Also, that looks like a GFF or GTF file, do you have headers?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this with GNU `grep`, as long as the strings `tree` and `train` only appear on the 2nd and 3rd fields respectively and not anywhere else:

```
$ grep -oP 'train\ttree\t.*leaf_id "\K[^"]+' file
ENSG00000223972
```

The `-o` makes `grep` only print the matched portion of the line and the `-P` enables Perl compatible regular expressions which give us `+` and `\K`.

The regex will search for `train`, followed by a `\t`, then `\tree` and another `\t`, then anything until it finds `leaf_id "`. Then, the `\K` tells `grep` to forget everything matched so far. So we now look for the longest stretch of non-`"` characters after this, which will be the gene name you're looking for.

---

To only match if `tree` and `train` are in the right columns, you can do:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$2=="train" && $3=="tree"' file | grep -oP 'leaf_id "\K[^"]+'
ENSG00000223972
```

Or:

```
$ perl -F'\t' -lane 'if($F[1] eq "train" && $F[2] eq "tree" && $F[8]=~/leaf_id\s+"\K([^"]+)/){print $1}' file
ENSG00000223972
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for this task. Assuming your file is called `input.tsv`, the relevant command would be:

```
awk -F"\t" '$2=="train" && $3=="tree" {split($9,f,"\""); print f[2]}' input.tsv
```

This will split the lines at every TAB (`-F"\t"`) into individual fields. If the second field is `train` and the third field is `tree`, inspect the 9th field and print the string inside the double quotes.

The latter is achieved by (mis-)using the `split()` command: The field is split at every double quotes, and all parts saved in the array variable `f`. The second entry `f[2]` (`awk` arrays *usually* start at 1) is then the string inside the quotes and is printed (the first entry of `f` would be `leaf_id`, the third would be `; root_id` etc.).

Comment: @terdon: Ooops, good catch - I spoke about the 9th field in the text but used the 10th in the `awk` command. But I think it is actually the 10th field (hoping I haven't lost my ability to count correctly ;) )

Comment: No, it's the 9th. Your command, with `$10`, doesn't produce any output. Also, this is a standard format, see https://github.com/The-Sequence-Ontology/Specifications/blob/master/gff3.md.

Comment: Ahhh, now I understand. I incorrectly assumed _all_ fields which appear as whitespace-separated in the sample input are actually tab-separated, but in reality, everything starting with `leaf_id` until the closing `;` is a single field _not_ containing tabs. Then of course you are right and it is the 9th field. I will revert my edit. I guess that is again one drawback of the code formatting tool, that it can't represent the tab character correctly ...

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. I just happen to be very familiar with this particular format, it is one I have been using for many years, so it was obvious to me. You're quite right that it isn't obvious from the OP if you don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed :

```
$ sed -nE 's/^.*train.*tree.*leaf_id "([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)";.*$/\1/p' file
ENSG00000223972
```